# re.match vs re.search

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

If i do this

```
    import re
    m = re.compile("[0-9]{1,}Y")
    res = m.search("AUD3M25Y_EOD2")
    if res:
            return res.group(0)[:-1]
```

I will get 25 as an answer

However if I do

```
    import re
    m = re.compile(".*([0-9]{1,})Y.*")
    res = m.match("AUD3M25Y_EOD2")
    if res:
            return res.groups(0)
```

I will get only 5.

Why the difference?

Does it have anything to do with 'global' option? (much like s///g in vi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your match, the first .* is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), it is matching as much as it can, including numbers.
If you make it less greedy, it will work:

```
 .*?([0-9]{1,})Y.*
```

(PS I think this greedy issue doesn't make it a fair comparison of re.search and re.match)

Comment: I'd also change the `{1,}` to `+` personally, as the `+` specificaly means one or more. Whilst I'm at it, `[0-9]` would be better displayed as `\d`. Might just be me, but I find `.*?(\d+)Y.*` a lot more readable than `.*?([0-9]{1,})Y.*`...

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation first. As you should expect, it has the answers.

[`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search):

> Scan through *string* looking for a location where the regular expression *pattern* produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of *string* match the regular expression *pattern*, return a corresponding match object. Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.
>
> > **Note:** If you want to locate a match anywhere in *string*, use `search()` instead.

Also, on the same page, [Matching vs. Searching](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: **match** checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while **search** checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).

Comment: A downvote for this seems rather harsh. He had two separate questions, really, and I answered one of them (while Niall answered the other).

Comment: Actually the documentation is a bit unclear. When I read it the first and second time, I still did not get the difference. Stating that if there is a match at the beginning `match` will return that doesn't exclude the possibility of match finding things which do not start at the beginning. Only the note makes it clear. A better wording would include something like "only if the match starts at the beginning of the string, it will be returned by `match`".